# How to import .dat file into Matlab?

Tags: matlab, file-io, import

i have one file (name.dat) which is binary data, 
it has 12 lines of header, then just one column of 10^6 floating data points.

I searched that in Matlab I can do

```
fid=fopen('name.dat','r');
A= fscanf(fid, '%f');
fclose(fid);
```

When run the three lines of code above, and A is empty;
it is wired.

Can you help me out of this ?

Thanks

Comment: Is it binary or textual file? (do you see normal text if you open it in a text editor)

Comment: yes, when I opened with Texshop, I found there are more than 200 lines of header, and then the real data are random symbols, just like machine code.  and  I changed the number of headerlines to 300, the result is still the same: empty

Comment: perhaps it is a binary file after all, and my answer below won't apply.. We can't offer more help unless you describe exactly how the file is structured (how did you get this file and what do you expect to be in it?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, I figure it out.
when I open my .dat file with text editor, it has headerlines, and data part.
I can see the header(ASCII), but the data part is random machine code, which means it is binary data, I also know it is floating point.

so instead of using "textscan or fscan", I use "fread" function in matlab to load the data.

Before loading into matlab, I deleted the header lines, if not deleted, the size of the data loaded is different and wrong.

```
fid=fopen('name.dat','rt');
A = fread(fid,'*float32');
fclose(fid);
```

A is the final array data.

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example using the TEXTSCAN function:

#### name.dat

```
header line 1
header line 2
0.81428
0.24352
0.92926
0.34998
0.1966
0.25108
0.61604
0.47329
0.35166
0.83083
```

#### MALTAB

```
fid = fopen('name.dat','rt');
A = textscan(fid, '%f', 'HeaderLines',2);
A = A{1};
fclose(fid);
```

`A` now is vector with the ten numbers

Comment: Thanks for reply!  I used your suggestions, it still doesn't work. 
the returned fid=3, so it should be opened, 
the A = textscan(fid, '%f', 'HeaderLines',12) is a 1*1 cell, returned with [0x1 double];
 However B=A{1} is Empty matrix: 0-by-1 (I replaced A with B for convenience).  
  it is annoying small problem.

Comment: @MikeSmith: can you post say the first 15 lines of your data file. Also are you certain that you have only numbers in one column after the header lines?

Comment: .dat file uses a mixed data type. The header is text (ascii) while the transient is stored as binary. Here are the first 15 lines: MIDAS Data File v3.30

Global Parameters

Trap DAC = 1
Process Count = 4194304
External Trigger Mode = 2
External Trigger Timeout = 20.0
Apodization = 1
Dumped Files = 0

Begin Experiment Sequence

expcount:100

experiment:EI

Comment: I dont know Why I can't post this data in column way.  sorry, It reads weird.

Comment: @MikeSmith: you should edit your question and add this information properly formatted